# How to get html code using injectedJavascript - React-native

Tags: html, react-native, react-native-web, react-native-webview

I wanna access the html code of youtube in react native. I need to use the injectedJavascript in order to render the youtube channel without the headerBar, so I tried :

```
    render(){

    let jsCode = `
        document.querySelector("header-bar").style.display = "none";
        `;

    return(
        <WebView
          style={{flex:1}}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4Hi8OVEbuY&list=PLSlVQ0kIy6qzezeIJZW6SAl-cMiyvvbhN'}}
          injectedJavascript={jsCode}
       />
    )
}
```

But it's not doing what I want, I think I'm not accessing it the good way. Can someone know how to do it ?

Thanks